# In java, input text and put them into a two Dimensional character array

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner, type-2-dimension

I am struggling to understand how to go about solving this problem. I am in need of resources to help me get a better understanding as to how to go about properly solving it or perhaps someone to explain it in another way that might help me get started. Or if someone can give me a starting point or provide an example of a code that is similar to this. I am very new at this and need it as "broke down" as possible so that I can understand all the basic fundamentals of it.

"Write a program that reads text from a file. Create a 2-dimensional character array that is 6 * 7. Store the characters read in your array in row major order (fill row 0 first, then row 1, etc.). Fill any unused spaces in the 2-D array with the ‘*’ character. If you have more characters than space, ignore the excess characters. Extract the characters from your array in column-major order (pull from column 0 first, then column 1, etc.). Build a new string as you extract the characters. Display the new string."

```
package programmingExercise5;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class twoDimensionalCharacterArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type in a sentence: ");
        String message = scan.nextLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : this will fill character space with '*' and fill the remain cell of Array 2D with '-'.

```
public class twoDimensionalCharacterArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int row = 6, col = 7;
        char[][] chars = new char[row][col];

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type in a sentence: ");
        String message = scan.nextLine();
        char[] messages = message.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < chars.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                if (i < messages.length) {
                    chars[r][c] = messages[i] == ' ' ? '*' : messages[i];
                    i++;
                } else {
                    chars[r][c] = '-';
                }
            }
        }
        for (char[] x : chars) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This really helps me out. Is there any way that you could break it down. I want to learn and understand more about coding.

Comment: Happy to hear from you, please kindly up vote my answer to be correct one! thanks you.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response to your comment. Just been reading my text books, forms online, just trying to get a better understanding of how everything things work. It wont let me, it say: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.". However, I did click that you answered it.

Comment: @Josh Thanks, that's okay. Let's help each other :)

Comment: Next time, please try to recap your question to short and understood one, so everyone passed by can easy to read and understand your problem faster!